# How to access private data members of a class in c++

Tags: c++

Following code is showing two error in my "struct node* createNode" function line 30 and 31.
The errors are 'temp' was not declared and invalid use of incomplete type 'struct node'. How to solve this problem??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myClass{
private:
    struct node{
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    };
    struct node *head, *last, *temp;
public:
    myClass();
    bool isEmpty();
    struct node *createNode();
    void insertElement();
    void deleteElement();
    void displayList();
};
myClass::myClass(){
    head=NULL;
    last=NULL;
    temp=NULL;
}
bool myClass::isEmpty(){
    if(head==NULL)return true;
    return false;
}
struct node *createNode(){
    temp = new node;
    return temp;
};
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tag lines at witch errors happend

Comment: Please edit your question to include the copy-pasted error, in full and complete and with any possible informational notes.

Comment: Looks like `createNode()` is not a member function.

Comment: The definition of `createNode` is missing a `myClass::` (or two). Compare to the lines above.

Comment: line no 31 @Tyker

Comment: Now we have to count through the lines?

Answer (score 2):

it is very strange to return a private type from a public membre fonction
but here is how it is done

```
myClass::node *myClass::createNode(){ 
    temp = new node;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Normally most getter functions in class return private variables. :)

Comment: @SumitJha its not about return private variable its about returning private type

Answer (score 0):

createNode() is a member of "myClass" class, change the definition to :

```
node *myClass::createNode(){
    temp = new node;
    return temp;
}
```

and remove that semicolon after this function